# Parse HTMLString (with input type text) to String.

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm really need your helps. I have this form with text and input fields.

[image]

I did a little bit jquery and get the big htmlString:

```
var StringContent = '<p>I am thrilled to share my new listing with you at <input id="additions_info_0_0" name="additions[0][replace][0]" size="21" type="text" value="Property Address"><input name="additions[0][find][0]" type="hidden" value="(MUST TYPE Property Address HERE)">. To find out more about this exciting property, or to hear about one of the many others currently on the market, call me to set up an appointment at <input id="additions_info_0_1" name="additions[0][replace][1]" size="17" type="text" value="Phone Number"><input name="additions[0][find][1]" type="hidden" value="(MUST TYPE Phone Number HERE)">. I would be happy to answer your questions, discuss your needs, and set you on track to achieving your real estate goals. Looking forward to hearing from you soon!</p>';
```

I can loop through the htmlString and get the input value, like "1003 Audelia, Houston, TX 75002" for input id = additions_info_0_0 and "469-999-9999" for id additions_info_0_1. But I can't combine all the string and input value into new string, like *I am thrilled to share my new listing with you at **1003 Audelia, Houston, TX 75002**. To find out more about this exciting property, or to hear about one of the many others currently on the market, call me to set up an appointment at **469-999-9999**. I would be happy to answer your questions, discuss your needs, and set you on track to achieving your real estate goals. Looking forward to hearing from you soon!*

I'm trying to parseHTML but no luck. Any helps would be awesome and much appreciated.

Comment: Whats the question? It's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear I hope this code will work fine for your requirement. 
Change your HTML in a similar manner like this,

```
<div id="contentDiv">
  <p>I am thrilled to share my new listing with you at
    <input id="additions_info_0_0" name="additions[0][replace][0]" size="21" type="text" value="Property Address">. To find out more about this exciting property, or to hear about one of the many others currently on the market, call me to set up an appointment at
    <input id="additions_info_0_1" name="additions[0][replace][1]" size="17" type="text" value="Phone Number"> I would be happy to answer your questions, discuss your needs, and set you on track to achieving your real estate goals. Looking forward to hearing from you soon!</p>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">
```

and your javascript code like this code

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function() {
  alert('test');
  var propertyAdd = $('#additions_info_0_0').val();
  var mobile = $('#additions_info_0_1').val();

  var StringContent = '<p>I am thrilled to share my new listing with you at ' + propertyAdd + '. To find out more about this exciting property, or to hear about one of the many others currently on the market, call me to set up an appointment at ' + mobile + ' I would be happy to answer your questions, discuss your needs, and set you on track to achieving your real estate goals. Looking forward to hearing from you soon!</p>';

  $('#contentDiv').html(StringContent);
});
```

This piece of code will first show the content from the HTML fine and after entering values you can click the button which will trigger the javascript code and take the two input values from the text boxes and re format the text to be show. Then you can change the initial content in the div to the formatted content according to your need.

Here I have done it with JQuery since you haven't mentioned how you want your code to be.